# xbindkeys: no process found

Tags: xbindkeys

I'm not getting xbindkeys to work.

I did this:

```
sudo aptitude install xbindkeys
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
sudo aptitude install xbindkeys-config
xbindkeys
xbindkeys-config
```

To begin with, it doesn't work.

Now, xbindkeys-config has a button in the top-left corner with the caption "Get Key". Although this button seems to work (when I press it and hit a command, it fetches it correctly what I can see) -- although this happens, xbindkeys-config (?) echoes to stdout "xbindkeys: no process found". If there is supposed to be such a process running all the time fetching X events, this is indeed not so, on `ps -e | grep x` I only get the usual stuff (i.e., no xbindkeys).

xbindkeys-config also has a way of running the command you wish to tie to a command. This works great, so it is not the "command side" of the thing that is non-responsive.

Just to type `xbindkeys` doesn't seem to do anything... I've also tried to run it in .xinitrc, both as a foreground and background process.

Comment: You sure you installed xbindkeys? `apt-cache policy xbindkeys`?

Comment: @Braiam well, he'd get a command not found error when trying to run xbindkeys had he not...

Comment: @derobert exactly, I followed his steps and didn't found any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following setup working here on Archlinux 64 Bit:

in my `.xinitrc` I execute `xbindkeys` as the first command (no `&`).
Running `ps -aux |grep xbindkeys` also returns the matching process. 
Using `xbindkeys --show`  will return the installed xbindkeys configuration, if there's no wonder it won't work. 
If executing `xbindkeys` won't start a process, you might want to check which exit code the execution of `xbindkeys` has. Therefore run `strace xbindkeys`, and the last line should print something like `+++ exited with 0 +++`. If this isn't the case there is a problem with your xbindkeys. For more reference on `xbindkeys` check out the [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)

Comment: No doubt, the problem is that the xbindkeys process won't start. With `strace xbindkeys`, there are approximately two pages of output, the three last lines being `close(3) = 0`, `close(4) = 0`, and `exit_group(0) = ?`